# GruntJS - Using one instance for multiple applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am using **Grunt** for building javascript apps.
Now I have multiple applications that work this way.

My question is: Is it possible to have **one grunt instance** on a certain central directory and use this for **multiple projects at the same time**?

For example: Can a have multiple grunt-watches for different projects running at the same time?

Would be nice to get some clarity here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Grunt main project folter "outside" your subproject folder.

```
-gruntJs folder
---gruntFile.js
-projectSubFolder
---project_1
-----sass
-----css
---project_2
-----sass
-----css
---project_3
-----sass
-----css
```

You can use dynamic parameters to pass in the task to target the single project you have:

for example:

```
grunt sass:<projectName>
```

than in the gruntFile.js you can use something like this:

```
sass: {
 dist: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        src: ['../projectSubFolder/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/sass/*.scss'],
        dest: '../projectSubFolder/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/css',
        extDot: 'last',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
 }
},
```

a generic task that execute it for all the project for example:

```
grunt.registerTask('sassAll', [ 'sass:project_1', 'sass:project_2', 'sass:project_3' ]);
```

it is good if you have multiple project that have the same tasks.
if you need to split the taskt than you can creare multiple different tasks, setting up the directory/process for it.

---

you can add multiple parameters for the grunt task if you want more versatility.

```
watch: {
 less: {
  files: ['../projectSubFolder/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/less/*.less',
          '../projectSubFolder/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/less/**/*.less',
          '../projectSubFolder/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/js/*.js'
        ],
  tasks: [
        'less:<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %><%= grunt.task.current.args[1] %>',
        'uglify:<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %><%= grunt.task.current.args[1] %>'
        ]
  },
},
less: {
 project_1: {
    options: {
      cleancss: true,
      compress: true
    },
    files: {
       '../projectSubFolder/<%= grunt.task.current.args[1] %>/css/style.min.css': '../projectSubFolder/<%= grunt.task.current.args[1] %>/less/*.less'
    }
  },
},

grunt watch:<projectName>:<taskName>
```